# XML Tag Counter

Tags: python, xml, python-3.x, counting

Please see attachment.  I am new to python (and programming in general; making a career switch; tldr: I am a noob at this).

I have no idea what function I can write that will return me the number of `xml` tags in the list.  Please help.  [image: attached image]

Comment: Click link titled "enter image description here" to see attachment.

Comment: [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/771848)

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the question:

> you can check if a string is an XML tag if it starts with `<` and ends with `>`

You need to iterate over every string in a list and use [`str.startswith()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.startswith) and [`str.endswith()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.endswith) to check the first and last characters:

```
In [1]: l = ["<string1>", "somethingelse", "</string1>"]

In [2]: [item for item in l if item.startswith("<") and item.endswith(">")]
Out[2]: ['<string1>', '</string1>']
```

Here we just filtered the desired strings in a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions), but to count how many matches we've got, we may use [`sum()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum) adding a `1` every time there is a match:

```
In [3]: sum(1 for item in l if item.startswith("<") and item.endswith(">"))
Out[3]: 2
```

---

This was though just one way to do it and I am not sure how far have you got in your course. A more naive and straightforward version of the answer might be:

```
def tag_count(l):
    count = 0
    for item in l:
        if item.startswith("<") and item.endswith(">"):
            count += 1
    return count
```

Comment: This was really helpful.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
tokens = ['<greeting>', 'Hello World!', '</greeting>']
count = 0

# write your for loop here
for token in tokens:
    if token.startswith("<") and token.endswith(">"):
            count += 1

print(count)
```

Comment: This would be a better answer if you explained how the code you provided answers the question.

Answer (score 0):

"For Approaching Tag Counter Problems"
Input:

```
tokens = ['<greeting>', 'Hello World!', '</greeting>']
count = 0

# write your for loop here
for XML_tag in tokens:
    if XML_tag.startswith('<') and  XML_tag.endswith('>'):
        count += 1
        print(XML_tag)        
print(count)

Output:
<greeting>
</greeting>
2
```

Answer (score -1):

```py
tokens = ['<greeting>', 'Hello World!', '</greeting>']

count = 0
for token in tokens:
    if token[0] == '<' and token[-1] == '>':
        count += 1

print(count)
```

Comment: This would be a better answer if you explained how the code you provided answers the question.